# API Pinterest in PHP - Login failed

Tags: php, pinterest

I used seregazhuk/php-pinterest-bot (in Symfony 4) to add pin on Pinterest (v5.9.0). When I tried to log in, something failed. Here my code:

```
    $mail = getenv("PINTEREST_MAIL");
    $pwd = getenv("PINTEREST_PASSWORD");

    $bot = PinterestBot::create();
    $res = $bot->auth->login($mail, $pwd); // return false

    $bot->getLastError(); // return NULL

    $boards = $bot->boards->forUser($username); // failed
```

When I look in logs, I've got the following error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception seregazhuk\PinterestBot\Exceptions\AuthRequired: "Error calling seregazhuk\PinterestBot\Api\Providers\Pins::create method. You must log in before."
```

I've already checked my mail, my username, and my password. I can connect successfully with them.

What's wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use the real Pinterest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved a few days ago after the publication of a new release 5.9.1. Now, you can use it again. The following method returns true as it should be:

```
$res = $bot->auth->login($mail, $pwd); // return true
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the lib you are using hasn't been working for a while:

https://github.com/seregazhuk/php-pinterest-bot/issues/442

Comment: Thank you for this link. Very interesting. So, I'll continue to search a solution!

Comment: Have you found any solution?